# Accessing Config Variables from External File

Tags: flask

I am building a Flask Web app and I am implementing a feature where users can upload their own images. I have three files I am working on to implement this feature:

- models.py: the file where I maintain the database structure and functions that can be called on entities within the database.
- routes.py: the file which handles the site's responses to HTTP requests on various URLs.
- __init__.py: where all of my config variables are set.

I have a function within models.py called avatar which returns a user's avatar. If they have not uploaded a photo it generates an avatar using gravatars MD5 hash generator. I want to change this function such that it first looks in my uploads file to see whether a user has uploaded a photo.

I have set up the upload feature such that users' photos will be saved in a folder with the format .. I have a config variable called UPLOAD_FOLDER which stores the absolute path to this folder. However, the problem is is that config variables are inaccessible from the models file. I have tried creating a local context as described in the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#creating-an-application-context) but am hit with a KeyError: 'UPLOAD_FOLDER' error.

models.py

```
from flask import Flask, current_app
from hashlib import md5
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), index = True, unique = True, nullable = False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable = False)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default = False)
    polls = db.relationship("Poll", backref = "author", lazy = "dynamic")
    votes = db.relationship("Votes", backref = "voter", lazy = "dynamic")

   def avatar(self, size):
      app = Flask(__name__)
      with app.app_context():
      UPLOAD_FOLDER = current_app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]
      if(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
         print("hooray")
      digest = md5(self.email.lower().encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
      return(("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{}?d=retro&s={}").format(digest, size))
```

__init__.py

```
import os 

dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
UPLOAD_FOLDER = dirname + "/static/user-images/"
ALLOWED_FILES = ["png", "jpeg", "jpg"]

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
app.config["ALLOWED_FILES"] = ALLOWED_FILES
```

routes.py

```
import os 
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_login import current_user

def allowed_file(file):
    return(file.filename.split(".")[1].lower() in app.config["ALLOWED_FILES"])

@app.route("/upload", methods = ["POST"])
@login_required
def upload_file():
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        if("file" not in request.files):
            print(request.files)
            flash("No file part")
            return(redirect("upload"))
        file = request.files["file"]
        if(not file.filename):
            flash("No file uploaded!")
            return(redirect("upload"))
        if(file and allowed_file(file)):
            extension = file.filename.split(".")[1]
            filename = secure_filename(str(current_user.id) + "." + extension)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))
            flash("Files successfully uploaded")
            return(redirect(url_for("user", username = current_user.username)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing your config variables to application context, why don't you just place them in a config file and import them wherever necessary?

Make a file named config.py

**config.py**

```
import os

dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

UPLOAD_FOLDER = dirname + "/static/user-images/"
ALLOWED_FILES = ["png", "jpeg", "jpg"]
MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 16 * 1024 * 1024
```

Then in routes.py import these config variables and use them, replace `app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]` with `UPLOAD_FOLDER`

**routes.py**

```
import os 
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_login import current_user
from config import UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(file):
    return(file.filename.split(".")[1].lower() in app.config["ALLOWED_FILES"])

@app.route("/upload", methods = ["POST"])
@login_required
def upload_file():
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        if("file" not in request.files):
            print(request.files)
            flash("No file part")
            return(redirect("upload"))
        file = request.files["file"]
        if(not file.filename):
            flash("No file uploaded!")
            return(redirect("upload"))
        if(file and allowed_file(file)):
            extension = file.filename.split(".")[1]
            filename = secure_filename(str(current_user.id) + "." + extension)
            file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename))
            flash("Files successfully uploaded")
            return(redirect(url_for("user", username = current_user.username)))
```

Do the same thing in models.py, replace `current_app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]` with `UPLOAD_FOLDER`.

**models.py**

```
from flask import Flask, current_app
from hashlib import md5
from config import UPLOAD_FOLDER
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), index = True, unique = True, nullable = False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable = False)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default = False)
    polls = db.relationship("Poll", backref = "author", lazy = "dynamic")
    votes = db.relationship("Votes", backref = "voter", lazy = "dynamic")

   def avatar(self, size):
      app = Flask(__name__)
      with app.app_context():
          upload_folder = UPLOAD_FOLDER  # please don't make normal variables UPPERCASE
          if(upload_folder):
             print("hooray")
          digest = md5(self.email.lower().encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
          return(("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{}?d=retro&s={}").format(digest, size))
```